# delphi XE-5 cross platform development - calling a showmodal form

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe5

I am currently developing cross platform applications on my Windows desktop using Delphi XE-5.  I have a unit I want to use for cross platform development (for this example, lets just work with Windows and Android).

In both my Windows and Android apps, I have a button with the following onClick event

```
procedure TfrmMain.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
LPSystem:=  TLPSystem.Create;
 try
   if LPSystem.execute then
   begin
    ShowMessage('Logged in!');
   end
   else
   ShowMessage('Not logged in!');
 finally
   LPSystem.Free;
 end;
end;
```

In the execute routine below, a ShowModal dialog is displayed to the user ( a different form depending on platform)

```
function TLPSystem.execute: Boolean;

var
 {$IFDEF MSWINDOWS}
  frmLoginW: TfrmLoginW;
 {$ENDIF MSWINDOWS}
 {$IFDEF Android}
 zResult: Boolean;
 frmLoginM: TfrmLoginM;
 {$ENDIF Android}
begin
  result:= False;
  {$IFDEF MSWINDOWS}
  frmLoginW:= TfrmLoginW.Create(nil);
  if frmLoginW.ShowModal = mrOK then
    begin
  {$ENDIF MSWINDOWS}

  {$IFDEF Android}
  frmLoginM:= TfrmLoginM.Create(nil);
  frmLoginM.ShowModal (procedure(ModalResult: TModalResult)
  begin
   if ModalResult = mrOK then
  begin
  {$ENDIF Android}


  {$IFDEF MSWINDOWS}
  end;
  frmLoginW.Free;
  {$ENDIF MSWINDOWS}

  {$IFDEF Android}
   end;
   end);
    if zResult then result:= zResult;
    frmLoginM.Free;
   {$ENDIF Android}
end;
```

This works great for windows, but on Android, I get my result (i.e., the showmessage) before I get the modal dialog box.  Not sure why?

Comment: Look at how ShowModal is done on Android in this link: http://blog.marcocantu.com/blog/xe5_anonymous_showmodal_android.html

Comment: @Sentient - I Believe that is what i am using - except for the DisposeOf method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take away your `IFDEF` statements and look at what you are actually doing:

Windows:

```
function TLPSystem.execute: Boolean;
var
  frmLoginW: TfrmLoginW;
begin
  Result := False;
  frmLoginW := TfrmLoginW.Create(nil);
  if frmLoginW.ShowModal = mrOK then
  begin
  end;
  frmLoginW.Free;
end;
```

This is functionally OK (though it is not assigning the `Result` based on the dialog's `ModalResult`).

Android:

```
function TLPSystem.execute: Boolean;
var
 zResult: Boolean;
 frmLoginM: TfrmLoginM;
begin
  Result := False;
  frmLoginM := TfrmLoginM.Create(nil);
  frmLoginM.ShowModal (
    procedure(ModalResult: TModalResult)
    begin
      if ModalResult = mrOK then
      begin
      end;
    end
  );
  if zResult then Result := zResult;
  frmLoginM.Free;
end;
```

This is not following the rules outlined in Embarcadero's documentation:

[ShowModal Dialogs in FireMonkey Mobile Apps](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/ShowModal_Dialogs_in_FireMonkey_Mobile_Apps)

To make matters worse, the overloaded version of `ShowModal()` that takes an anonymous procedure runs asynchronously, so your `Execute()` would exit before the modal Form is closed.  It cannot wait on the Form before exiting.  So you will have to redesign your code to handle that.

Try something more like this:

```
type
  TLPSystemLoginEvent = procedure(LoggedIn: Boolean) of object;

  TLPSystem = class
  private
    procedure DoLoginResult(LoggedIn: Boolean);
  public
    OnLoginResult: TLPSystemLoginEvent;
    procedure Execute;
  end;

procedure TLPSystem.DoLoginResult(LoggedIn: Boolean);
begin
  if Assigned(OnLoginResult) then OnLoginResult(LoggedIn);
end;

procedure TLPSystem.Execute;
var
  {$IFDEF MSWINDOWS}
  frmLoginW: TfrmLoginW;
  {$ENDIF}
  {$IFDEF Android}
  frmLoginM: TfrmLoginM;
  LSelf: TLPSystem;
  {$ENDIF}
begin
  {$IFDEF MSWINDOWS}
  frmLoginW := TfrmLoginW.Create(nil);
  try
    DoLoginResult(frmLoginW.ShowModal = mrOK);
  finally
    frmLoginW.Free;
  end;
  {$ENDIF}

  {$IFDEF Android}
  frmLoginM := TfrmLoginM.Create(nil);
  LSelf := Self;
  frmLoginM.ShowModal(
    procedure(ModalResult: TModalResult)
    begin
      LSelf.DoLoginResult(ModalResult = mrOK);
    end
  );
  {$ENDIF}
end;
```

```
procedure TfrmLoginM.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  Action := TCloseAction.caFree;
end;
```

```
procedure TfrmMain.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  LPSystem: TLPSystem;
begin
  LPSystem := TLPSystem.Create;
  {$IFDEF MSWINDOWS}
  try
  {$ENDIF}
    LPSystem.OnLoginResult := LoginResult;
    LPSystem.Execute;
  {$IFDEF MSWINDOWS}
  finally
    LPSystem.Free;
  end;
  {$ENDIF}
end;

procedure TfrmMain.LoginResult(LoggedIn: Boolean);
begin
  if LoggedIn then
    ShowMessage('Logged in!')
  else
    ShowMessage('Not logged in!');
end;
```

Alternatively, you can get rid of the `try/finally` on Windows by utilizing an ARC `interface`:

```
type
  TLPSystemLoginEvent = procedure(LoggedIn: Boolean) of object;

  ILPSystem = interface
    procedure Execute;
  end;

  TLPSystem = class(TInterfacedObject, ILPSystem)
  private
    fOnLoginResult: TLPSystemLoginEvent;
    procedure DoLoginResult(LoggedIn: Boolean);
  public
    constructor Create(ALoginResult: TLPSystemLoginEvent);
    procedure Execute;
  end;

constructor TLPSystem.Create(ALoginResult: TLPSystemLoginEvent);
begin
  inherited Create;
  fOnLoginResult := ALoginResult;
end;

procedure TLPSystem.DoLoginResult(LoggedIn: Boolean);
begin
  if Assigned(fOnLoginResult) then fOnLoginResult(LoggedIn);
end;

procedure TLPSystem.Execute;
var
  {$IFDEF MSWINDOWS}
  frmLoginW: TfrmLoginW;
  {$ENDIF}
  {$IFDEF Android}
  frmLoginM: TfrmLoginM;
  LSelf: ILPSystem;
  {$ENDIF}
begin
  {$IFDEF MSWINDOWS}
  frmLoginW := TfrmLoginW.Create(nil);
  try
    DoLoginResult(frmLoginW.ShowModal = mrOK);
  finally
    frmLoginW.Free;
  end;
  {$ENDIF}

  {$IFDEF Android}
  frmLoginM := TfrmLoginM.Create(nil);
  LSelf := Self;
  frmLoginM.ShowModal(
    procedure(ModalResult: TModalResult)
    begin
      (LSelf as TLPSystem).DoLoginResult(ModalResult = mrOK);
    end
  );
  {$ENDIF}
end;
```

```
procedure TfrmLoginM.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  Action := TCloseAction.caFree;
end;
```

```
procedure TfrmMain.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  LPSystem: ILPSystem;
begin
  LPSystem := TLPSystem.Create(LoginResult);
  LPSystem.Execute;
end;

procedure TfrmMain.LoginResult(LoggedIn: Boolean);
begin
  if LoggedIn then
    ShowMessage('Logged in!')
  else
    ShowMessage('Not logged in!');
end;
```

Comment: Sorry, but this routine does not work for windows or android! There is no where you instantiate a frmLoginW (Windows dialog form), only the android one (frmLoginM). I believe there should be a var for each object in their respective IFDEFs. With the android section, it displays the result before it displays the dialog box - just like in the other question I posted and you posted an answer to.  On another note, i was able to edit the code and get the windows version working by adding the for instantiation code and placing it in the appropriate IFDEF

Comment: Your right about the showmessages. I am not even able to use them on the main form side. if I get rid of the ShowMessages there, then the modal form gets shown first. I dont understand why this is, but i guess i can make do with out them.

Comment: @LuvRAD: good catch about `frmLoginW`, I did not even notice that the two platforms were using different class types. I have adjusted my answer.

Comment: `ShowModal` is not blocking on mobile compilers. Last example wont work in Android since zResult is not initialized when execute exits. Also the `DisposeOf` call is wrong since the anonymous frame relies on the object to be valid when ModalResult is returned. Even if this is fixed, `ShowModal` is not recommended for use on mobile compilers. Use `Show` instead.

Comment: I updated my answer to take a different approach using `ShowModal()`.