# Get modalresult from function in Firemonkey Multi Device Delphi project

Tags: android, ios, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10-seattle

I have a Firemonkey Multi Device(Android & iOS) Project in Rad Studio 10 Seattle.
I want to call a form with showmodal from a method in a unit and give the modalresult back with the function.

**I've tried the following examples below:**

```
function ShowMyForm: TModalResult;
var
  form: TForm1;
begin
  form:= TForm1.Create(nil);
  form.ShowModal(
    procedure(ModalResult: TModalResult)
    begin
      result := ModalResult;
    end);
end;

function ShowMyForm: TModalResult;
var
  form: TForm1;
begin
  form:= TForm1.Create(nil);
  result := form.ShowModal;
end;
```

With the inline procedure the function can't access the result.

And just calling TForm.ShowModal doesn't work on a multi device project.

***Is there an other way to achieve this?***

Comment: From [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Forms.TCommonCustomForm.ShowModal): **Caution:** *Modal dialog boxes are not supported in Android apps. Instead of calling ShowModal, you should call Show, and have the form return and call your event. We recommend that you not use modal dialogs on either of the mobile platforms (iOS and Android) because unexpected behavior can result. Not using modal dialogs eliminates potential problems in debugging and supporting your mobile apps.*

Comment: In mobile compilers, `ShowModal` is not blocking. This means that your function `ShowMyForm` is complete before the modal form is executed. Instead do as docs says, call `Show` and let the form return and call your event.

Comment: @LURD only problem there is that I want to use it for a lot of different things. So not 1 single event.

Comment: Pass the event code in an anonymous method. That way it is not tied to a single solution.

Comment: @LURD can you give an example? If it works i'll accept it as an answer

Comment: @KenWhite I've tried the example of Remy, but it doesn't work for Android. The result doesn't get set. Answer is also for XE5 and not for Seattle

Comment: @KenWhite no it does not work! The result of the function won't wait on the modalresult. Showmodal with inline procedure runs in a seperate thread so the function where it's called won't wait on it. Try it yourself

Comment: @KenWhite, docs are wrong and has changed from XE7. They removed the `DisposeOf` call, since that was dangerous on mobile compilers. Even then, it is not good for mobile, see my comment above, that ShowModal must not be used on mobile compilers.

Comment: @RemyLebeau updated his answer [delphi XE-5 cross platform development - calling a showmodal form](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22213680/576719). I suggest you try it and report back if it is ok.

Comment: @LURD I've sort of solved my problem the same way. I'll show in my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've solved my problem by adding an inline procedure that's called when modalresult equals mrOk.

**Code below:**

*Method for showing my Form with showmodal*

```
procedure ShowMyForm(event: TProc = nil);
var
  form: TForm1;
begin
  form:= TForm1.Create(nil);
  form.ShowModal(
    procedure(ModalResult: TModalResult)
    begin
      if (ModalResult = mrOk) and Assigned(event) then
        event;  
    end);
end;
```

*The call of the procedure with an inline procedure.*

```
ShowMyForm(
      procedure
      begin
          // Code that you want to do on mrOk
      end);
```